# signal: Segmentation fault(11) when shutdown PC

Tags: kubuntu, segmentation-fault

I have Kubuntu 18.10 with KDE Plasma 5.14.4 on a Lenovo ideapad 320 with upgraded RAM.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 18.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.14.4
Qt Version: 5.11.1
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.52.0
Kernel Version: 4.18.0-13-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Pentium® CPU 4415U @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 11.5 GiB of RAM

Upgraded RAM: Kingston DDR4-2400 SC - 8GB DDR4, 8 GB, SO DIMM 260-PIN, 2400 MHz / PC4-19200
```

When I shutdown I get prompted Segmentation fault (11) and a PID.

How do I get rid of the fault?

Anything else works perfectly.

Comment: Does `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/dmesg` give any hints on whats happening at shutdown ?

Comment: I have No such file or directory.